# Microsoft Unity, parameters in constructor

Tags: unity-container, enterprise-library

I am using Unity with MVC and NHibernate. Unfortunately, our UnitOfWork resides in a different .dll and it doesn't have a default empty .ctor.
This is what I do to register NHibernate:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    ["jobManagerConnection"].ConnectionString;
var assemblyMap = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["assemblyMap"];
container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

In my WebController I have this:

```
/// <summary>Gets or sets UnitOfWork.</summary>
[Dependency]
public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
```

The problem is that the constructor of UnitOfWork expects 2 mandatory strings. How I can setup the RegisterType for this Interface in order to pass the two parameters retreived from the web.config?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier than I though:

```
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jobManagerConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var assemblyMap = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["assemblyMap"];
        container
            .RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
            .Configure<InjectedMembers>()
            .ConfigureInjectionFor<UnitOfWork>(new InjectionConstructor(connectionString, assemblyMap));
```

Comment: I couldn't get Mark's syntax for the constructor parameters to work for some reason, but your lengthier implementation worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should do it:

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
    ["jobManagerConnection"].ConnectionString;
var assemblyMap = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["assemblyMap"];

container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(
    new InjectionConstructor(connectionString, assemblyMap),
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: Yep, Mark you are right. I just posted a different way.
Sorry but the docs in Unity still lack.

Comment: Mark's got it almost right - you need to put the lifetime manager first:

container.RegisterInstance<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionConstructor(connectionString, assembyMap));